# How is your approach for creating your own set of controls aka own Extensions Library?

Tags: xpages

What is your approach for creating your own set of controls  aka own Extensions Library? After a few years of Xpages development we have a huge set of controls that are general purpose for building UI, some web services etc. (Probably as most other developers.) When we start a new project now we have to copy the entire stuff from one database to new one which involves controls, jars, css, images, JAVA code ... and then you completely loose control to maintain some central version of this controls & codes, everything is scattered among several projects/databases and things get messy fast.

We have thought about creating our own extension library as described here
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Master_Table_of_Contents_for_XPages_Extensibility_APIs_Developer_Guide but there is not enough documentation for this topic and the entire development process is quite complicated (at least seems to me. I tried two times based on docs above going through eclipse plugin project -> feature project -> update site and still having some bugs around)

What is your experience and approach for creating and maintaining shared Xpages controls in your Domino environment? Is there some hidden feature we miss here that can help us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [XSP Starter Kit](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit) on OpenNTF and the [XPages SDK](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP) to setup an eclipse environment for plugin development. You'll also want [Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junosr2). Install the starter kit and SDK into eclipse and you should be all set.

The starter kit is a sample plugin with all kinds of examples of phase listeners, components, etc. Once you want to deploy your plugin, create an update site from within eclipse and use the Update Site NSF available on your server install to place your update site. Once that's done, you can replicate that NSF to any other servers that may need the plugin.

For more information about the starter kit, take a look at [this slide deck](http://www.slideshare.net/NotesSensei/the-xsp-starter-kit). There is also a [github project](https://github.com/the-ntf/xspstarterkit) for the starter kit. Documentation for the XPages SDK can be found [here](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/AAD4D6A98E4C36CA86257997007B7065/%24file/SDK%20Instructions%20Draft%201.pdf). And a video for setting up the SDK is [available on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dchOyzjy9L4). Lastly, here's the documentation for setting up the [update site NSF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_CREATE_IMPORT_NSF_UPDSITE_STEPS.html).

Answer (score 1):

While we haven't gotten to that yet in XPages, our model for regular Notes design elements is to have a central template that contains the elements that are shared, with those specific design elements marked to inherit from that template. Sometimes, a database inherits design elements from two different central templates.

That way, those centrally controlled design elements remain the same in all databases.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at some example's on github for how they have library/components setup.  One of the more simpler examples that has just a single component built into a Library is Steve Pridemore's App Layout Extension...https://github.com/DominoDev, Another good one is Nathan Freeman's Starterkit:  https://github.com/the-ntf/xspstarterkit.  Hopefully these will help you get the file structure down on which files you need and how they work.